# Ternary operator compilation

Tags: c++

Why does this giving compilation problem at bold line?

```
#include<iostream>

static int i = 10; 

int main() {
  **(i) ? (std::cout << "First i = " << i << std::endl) : ( i = 10);**
  std::cout << "Second i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation message:

```
test.c:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int’
```

Comment: \*\*(i) ? (std::cout << "First i = " << i << std::endl) : ( i = 10);\*\* looks like, you are using markdown language in C++ ?

Comment: Ignore this **.

This came while I was trying to make this line bold.

Comment: In an expression `a ? b : c`, `b` and `c` need to be of compatible types (i.e. each can unambiguously be converted to the other).   In your case `b` is a (reference to) `std::cout`  - a `std::ostream` - and `c` is `(i = 10)` which is of type `int`.   `std::ostream` and `int` are not unambiguously convertable to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of the ternary operator is a bit weird: based on the value of `i`, you either print something to `std::cout` or assign a new value to it. Those actions don't share a connection through the return value of an expression, so don't do it like this. When using the ternary operator, it's best to stay closer to its intended purpose: a short notation for two possible expressions with a dispatch based on a simple predicate. Example:

```
const int n = i == 0 ? 42 : 43;
```

Your code should look like this:

```
if (i == 0)
   i = 10;
else
   std::cout << "First i = " << i << "\n";
```

The reason the original snippet did not compile is that there is no common return type of the ternary operator. "Common" means that both expressions can be converted to the return type. E.g., in `const int n = i == 0 ? 42 : 43;` the return type is `int`.

Comment: Acepted this answer because of 'conversion comment'. I was not aware about that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that the return values of the expressions in your conditional operator (*ternary operator*) (`std::ofstream` in the case of the `std::cout ...`, and `int` for `i = 10`) are incompatible and therefore the conditional operator is ill-formed. Please check [the rules for return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) of the conditional operator.

In this case, just use a normal conditional:

```
if (i)
  std::cout << "First i = " << i << std::endl;
else
  i = 10;
```